# Why is stepper motor jittering when approaching body part near driver until I touch the motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am controlling a Nema17 stepper motor with a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 using an A4988 stepper motor driver.

When my python program finishes, the motor (which has still power) doesn't move, has I expect.

However, when I approach my hand/arm/head/etc. near the breadboard with the A4988 driver or near the Raspberry Pi, without touching anything, the motor jitters in (what seems to be) a random way!

If I touch the body/shaft/shaft coupler/screw touching body/wire touching body/... of the motor while it jitters, it stops jittering. And I even found out that this only works if I'm sitting. Touching it while standing up does not stop it from jittering.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Two things to check: Have you omitted any pull-down resistors on unused inputs? Should the metal parts be grounded?

Comment: Did you connect the ground between the Pi and the stepper drivers?  That could explain that behaviour.

Comment: Yes, the stepper driver is connected at Vmot and GND (to a 12V adapter) and at VDD and GND (to the raspberry pi) on the other side